# Opencv: Good point matches but wrong homography

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, homography, perspectivecamera

I'm trying to extract the homography matrix between two images. The original planar image and another image that contains the first one. I'm following the steps in this tutorial https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#feature-homography.

The matches found look great, but when drawing the box containing the image it looks wrong because it doesn't contain the image...but one of the borders is ok... So what's going on? Is the homography matrix wrong or is it simply a visualization problem?

[image: Bad bounding box]

My piece of code looks like:

```
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

h,w = self.poster_original.shape
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0],[0,h-1]]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
self.undistorted_camera_image= cv2.polylines(self.undistorted_camera_image,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

EDIT:
Changing the order of the corners to:

```
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
```

I get things like:

[image: bb2]

[image: bb3]

That looks a bit different but still not what I expected.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's wrong"?

Comment: I expect the bounding box all around the image...

Comment: Not sure what bounding box you are referring to.

Comment: The white lines in the right image. They are intended to be the borders of the image

Comment: I have the same problem. Does the problem fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

When you define your blunding box, you specify these corners

```
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0],[0,h-1]]).reshape(-1,1,2)
```

but the example uses

```
pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
```

Theirs will form a square (top-left -> bottom-left -> bottom-right -> top-right), yours will form something else (top-left -> bottom-right -> top-right -> bottom-left).

Comment: Right. You have a point, but it isn't solved yet... I've updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong the homography is right: two of the corners and the alignment of the lines is completely correct.

The problem appears when there are corners of the poster that are behind the camera.... As they are behind, the projection of the point doesn't have sense: you can not project a 3d point that is in the negative part of the opitcal axis, hence drawing the corners of the poster doesn't make any sense, however the homography is correct.

This explains why in other images where you can see the whole poster I can draw the poster borders perfectly.

Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: you can try this by painting/transforming not the whole box but e.g. the centre of the box or half the box or a grid all over the box.